# Proving that the following ensemble is not vector space if $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to check if my method to show that $F$ is not a vector space with $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ is true.

$$ F = \{(x,y,z) / x^2+y^2+2z^2-2xy-2yz+2xz=0 \}$$

$x^2+y^2+2z^2-2xy-2yz+2xz=0 \Leftrightarrow (x+z-y)^2+z^2=0 \Leftrightarrow (x+z-y)^2=-z^2$

This equation admit solutions only if $z=i \alpha$.

We have :

$(x+i\alpha-y)^2=\alpha^2 \Leftrightarrow x=\pm \alpha +y -i \alpha$

Finally my space of solutions is :

$F=Span((\pm 1-i;0;i),(1;1;0))$

And because of the $\pm$, I can say that I have a union of two vectorial spaces :

$F_1=Span((+1-i;0;i),(1;1;0))$ and $F_2=Span((-1-i;0;i),(1;1;0))$

Thus $F=F_1 \cup F_2$

And as $F_1$ and $F_2$ are disjoint (the first is not included and the second and same for the second is not in the first), the global ensemble is not a vector space.

Am I right ?

Comment: $(\pm 1 -i, 0,i)\in F$, but their sum isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:
\begin{align*}
(x,y,z) \in F \iff (x+z-y)^2+z^2 &= 0 \\\iff (x+z-y+iz)(x+z-y-iz) &= 0
\end{align*}
I agree with that $F$ is the union of two subspaces $F_1$ and $F_2$:
\begin{align*}
    F_1 &= \left\{(x,y,z)\mid x - y + (1+i) z = 0\right\}\\
    F_2 &= \left\{(x,y,z)\mid x - y + (1-i) z = 0\right\}
\end{align*}
You're right that neither $F_1$ nor $F_2$ contains the other (I don't think it's conventional to use *disjoint* for this condition; I think of *disjoint* as meaning “having empty intersection”, and subspaces always share at least the zero vector).

I'm not sure exactly how best to get from here to the conclusion that $F$ is not a subspace.  My preference would be to show it violates one of the subspace conditions.  For instance, let $v_1 = (-1-i, 0, 1)$ and $v_2 = (-1+i,0,1)$.  Then $v_1 \in F_1$ and $v_2 \in F_2$, so they are both in $F$.  Their sum is
$$
    v_1 + v_2 = (-2,0,2)
$$
This point does not satisfy the equation defining $F$.  Since $F$ is not closed under addition, $F$ cannot be a subspace.